# Move a player in the direction it is facing? Using transform matrix

Tags: c++, math, visual-studio-2017

I have two characters in 3d space. I want the enemy to move towards the player. 
I've just finished making a function which takes the transform of two objects, and returns a matrix, which I then apply to my enemy (overwrite the position part), and as a result he is always looking at the player. I can't figure out how can I have him move in that direction.

Comment: You have to be specific. Please add a [mcve] and I mean minimal. Don't try to link 100s to thousands of lines of code from some repository.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume each character has a position so you should be able to add operators to do `P1 - P2` to get the 3D vector diff. With that, just normalize the vector length to the speed of the character. This will run a simulation where the enemy runs towards the player and the player tries to flee, but is slower, so the enemy will catch the player in the end.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

struct Position {
    double x;
    double y;
    double z;
    Position& operator+=(const Position& other) {
        x += other.x;
        y += other.y;
        z += other.z;
        return *this;
    }
    Position operator+(const Position& other) const {
        Position rv(*this);
        rv += other;
        return rv;
    }
    Position& operator-=(const Position& other) {
        x -= other.x;
        y -= other.y;
        z -= other.z;
        return *this;
    }
    Position operator-(const Position& other) const {
        Position rv(*this);
        rv -= other;
        return rv;
    }
    Position operator-() const {
        Position rv(*this);
        rv.x = -rv.x;
        rv.y = -rv.y;
        rv.z = -rv.z;
        return rv;
    }
    Position& operator*=(double f) {
        x *= f;
        y *= f;
        z *= f;
        return *this;
    }
    double length() const {
        return std::sqrt(x*x + y*y + z*z);
    }
    void normalize(double max_speed) {
        double len=length();
        if(len>max_speed) {
            *this *= max_speed/len;
        }
    }
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const Position&);
};
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Position& pos) {
    os << "{" << pos.x << "," << pos.y << "," << pos.z << "}";
    return os;
}

int main() {
    Position enemy{100, 100, 100};
    Position player{50, 150, 20};
    Position enemy_aim;
    Position player_flee;

    while( (enemy_aim = player-enemy).length()>0 ) {
        std::cout << "distance: " << enemy_aim.length() << "\n";
        std::cout << "enemy: " << enemy << "  player: " << player << "\n";

        player_flee = enemy_aim;    // player runs in the same direction (to get away)
        player_flee.normalize(5);   // the max speed of the player is 5
        player += player_flee;      // do the players move

        enemy_aim = player-enemy;   // recalc after players move
        enemy_aim.normalize(10);    // the max speed of the enemy is 10
        enemy += enemy_aim;         // do the enemys move
    }
    std::cout << "enemy: " << enemy << "  player: " << player << "\n";
}
```

Comment: Thank you.  I used this as a base and made it work.

Comment: Great that it worked!